# Virtual Column based query performance without index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I set a virtual column based on a JSON type column in Mysql 8.0.19 version and set secondary indexes for it.

But, in some cases, virtual column-based indexes are not used due to complex query conditions.

In this case, would MySQL re-parsing each JSON columns for SELECT query?

If that's true, I need to set an index for all conditions that use virtual columns.

**example**:

1. create & insert

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `json` json NOT NULL,
  `optional` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `_virtual_column` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_extract(`json`,'$.val')) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `_index` (`_virtual_column`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`json`, `optional`) VALUES ('{\"val\":1, \"val2\":2}', '1');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`json`) VALUES ('{\"val\":1, \"val2\":2}');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`json`, `optional`) VALUES ('{\"val\":3, \"val2\":3}', '3');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`json`, `optional`) VALUES ('{\"val\":3, \"val2\":4}', '4');
```

2. query without index

```sql
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE optional != null AND id < 3 AND optional = 1 AND _virtual_column >= 1;
```

It's a strange query I made for the situation where the index is not used.

Anyway, I wonder if virtual column parsing is processed if virtual column-based indexes are not used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid:  `optional != null`

You need:  `optional IS NOT null`

But, you don't need to check for `NULL`, since `optional = 1` will fail for `NULL`.

Now the query is down to

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  test_table
    WHERE  id < 3
      AND  optional = 1
      AND  _virtual_column >= 1;
```

For that, I would recommend adding these two 'composite' indexes:

```
INDEX(optional, id),
INDEX(optional, _virtual_column)
```

(`optional` is first since it is tested with `=`)

It is not uncommon for the Optimizer to shun the use of an index.  This usually happens when "too much" of the index needs to be scanned for the query at hand.  For example, if "most" of the table satisfied `_virtual_column >= 1`, it is unlikely to use the `INDEX(_vertical_column)`.

Since there are only 2 values of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` satisfying `id < 3`, I would hope that the Optimizer would simply read the table -- and pick whichever of id=1 and id=2 that satisfy the rest of the filtering conditions.  That *will* be faster than using any secondary index.

Note that the "1" and "3" in the query may be important in optimizing.  So, if they are really "12345" and "98765", I (and the Optimizer) may take a different approach.

Said another way, my suggested indexes are likely to speed up some queries, while being ignored from queries that would be 'fast' even without the indexes.